# Narrator Pitch on Variables in VBS

Tags: vbscript, sapi, pitch, narrator

I am writing a script in VBS for when I log in I am greeted with the time. However, the XML variable for voice pitch is not functioning without text that is static. Am I missing something?

```
Sapi.speak "<PITCH MIDDLE = '5'/>Good Morning"
```

This runs at a higher pitch...

```
Sapi.speak minute(time)
```

While this is normal.

I have tried `"<PITCH MIDDLE = '5'/> minute(time)"`, `<PITCH MIDDLE = '5'/>middle(time)`, and `"<PITCH MIDDLE = '5'/>"middle(time)`.
All of which return with errors.

I appreciate any help that is given. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass to the `Speak` method is a string. You are trying to pass a string and a number, so, all you should need to do is to concatenate both using the `&` concatenate operator to obtain a string with the full content

```
Sapi.speak "<PITCH MIDDLE = '5'/>" & Minute(Time)
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer! Been 1 month since I asked and it finally works! Thank you so much!